# Why this synchronisation is not working in given scenario?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, singleton

```
package singleton;

public class SingletonClass {

    private static SingletonClass singleton = null;

    private SingletonClass() {
    }

    static boolean stopThread = true;

    //approach 1 which fails in multithereaded env
    /*public static SingletonClass getInstance(){
        if(null == singleton){
            try {
                if(stopThread){
                    stopThread = false;
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            singleton = new SingletonClass();
        }
        return singleton;
    }*/

    //approach 2 which works
    //method is synchronized
   /* public static synchronized SingletonClass getInstance(){
        if(null == singleton){
                try {
                    if(stopThread){
                        stopThread = false;
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                singleton = new SingletonClass();

        }
        return singleton;
    }*/

    ***//approach 3 which is failing but I don't understand why
   //big block of code is synchronized
    public static SingletonClass getInstance(){
        if(null == singleton){
            synchronized (SingletonClass.class){
                try {
                    if(stopThread){
                        stopThread = false;
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                singleton = new SingletonClass();
            }
        }
        return singleton;
    }***


    //small block of code is synchronized, checked null again because even object instantiation is synchronised
    //if we don't check null, it will create new object once again
    //approach 4 which works
   /* public static SingletonClass getInstance(){
        if(null == singleton){
                try {
                    if(stopThread){
                        System.out.println("in thread...");
                        stopThread = false;
               //even if we interchange above 2 lines it makes whole lot of difference
               //till the time it takes to print "in thread"
               //2nd thread reaches there n enters if(stopThread) block because
               //stopThread is still true because 1st thread spent time in writing that sentence and 
               //did not set stopThread = false by the time 2nd thread reached there
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                synchronized (SingletonClass.class){
                    System.out.println("in this block");
                    if(null == singleton){
                        singleton = new SingletonClass();
                    }
                }
        }
        return singleton;
    }*/

}


---------------------------------------------------------

package singleton;

public class ThreadUsage implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        SingletonClass singletonOne = SingletonClass.getInstance();
        System.out.println(singletonOne.hashCode());
    }
}

----------------------------------------------------------------

package singleton;

class ThreadUsageTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnableOne = new ThreadUsage();
        Runnable runnableTwo = new ThreadUsage();
        new Thread(runnableOne).start();
        new Thread(runnableTwo).start();
    }
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In approach 3, it's not giving same hashCode for 2 objects, I've kept both Thread.sleep as well as object instantiation under synchronised block so what I'm thinking is , 2nd thread should not even enter this block until 1st finishes, but it's still doing and creating 2nd object leading to diff hashCode. What am I mssing here? Could someone correct my understanding here ? If I check for null b4 object creation then it's working as expected but why would I need to check null again here because my entire code is under synchronised block?

```
if(null == singleton)
       singleton = new SingletonClass();
```

Comment: You are getting two instances because you are checking for null outside the synchronized block. Put the check inside or make the whole method synchronized.

Comment: Use double locking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way that code (approach 3) ends up creating and returning two (or more) separate objects for the singleton:

- Thread A enters the function and sees `null` for `singleton`
- Thread B enters the function and sees `null` for `singleton`
- Thread A enters the synchronized block
- Thread B waits because it can't enter the synchronized block
- Thread A assigns to `singleton`
- Thread A exits the synchronized block
- Thread A returns one object
- Thread B enters the synchronized block
- Thread B assigns to `singleton`
- Thread B returns a different object

E.g., there's a gap between the `null` check and entering the synchronized block that follows it.

To solve it, just make `getInstance` a `synchronized` method and remove the `synchronized` block inside it:

```
public static synchronized SingletonClass getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
            singleton = new SingletonClass();
    }
    return singleton;
}
```

Or if you really want to avoid synchronization on subsequent calls, on Java 5 or later (which hopefully you're using!), declare `singleton` `volatile` and check again within the `synchronized` block:

```
private static volatile SingletonClass singleton;
// ...
public static SingletonClass getInstance() { // Only works reliably on Java 5 (aka 1.5) and later!
    SingletonClass instance = singleton;
    if (instance == null) {
        synchronized (SingletonClass.class) {
            instance = singleton;
            if (instance == null) {
                singleton = instance = new SingletonClass();
            }
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

That's the *double-checked locking* idiom. In Java 4 (aka 1.4) and earlier that wasn't necessarily reliable, but it is now (provided you use `volatile` on the member).

In a comment user2683814 asked a good question:

> Could you explain the assignment to local variable before null check in the second code snippet ? Checking the class variable directly won’t work ?

Yes, it would work, but less efficiently.

In cases where `singleton` is non-`null`, using a local means the method only accesses `singleton` **once**. If the code didn't use a local, it would access `singleton` at least **twice** (once to check it, once to return it). Since accessing a `volatile` variable is slightly expensive, better to use the local (which in the code above can be optimized into a register).

That may seem like premature micro-optimization, but if you weren't doing this in performance-critical code, you'd just make the method `synchronized` and avoid the complexity of double-checked locking entirely. :-)

Comment: Could you explain the assignment to local variable before null check in the second code snippet ? Checking the class variable directly won’t work ?

Comment: @user2683814 - Good question! I've added the question and an answer to it to the answer.

Comment: It’s also a good habit in general. When you check a condition and act on it, ensure that the condition is still valid while acting. So when you read a `volatile` variable, to return the value when non-`null`, remember the value in a local variable to ensure that it is this very non-`null` value you’re returning and not a potentially new value, read when accessing the shared variable a second time. In this specific scenario, the variable won’t go back to `null` again, but, as said, it’s a good habit to always avoid “check-then-act” patterns.

Comment: @Holger - Big time.

Answer (score 1):

In approach three, you do a check on the `singleton` variable; you do this **outside** of any synchronized block, which is why it doesn't work: There is no guarantee here that threads wait before checking. They all check as fast as they can, which is why 2+ threads may all see a null here, even as one of them is already at work making that instance.

You then synchronize, sure. However, that doesn't magically give this code 'only assign singleton once' powers - after all, the code in that singleton block IS going to assign a newly created instance of `SingletonClass` to the `singleton` variable.

Two relevant notes:

[1] The java memory model states that any given field is like schroedinger's cat: Each thread has a copy of it, or doesn't - up to the threading model. An individual copy is sent out to each other thread's copy, or to some of them, at arbitrary times, and the same goes for receiving updates from the others. You can't rely on this mechanism, it may not even be used, there is no way to control it (other than `volatile` which can help but it's a bit tricky to use correctly). The point is to write your code such that it can't matter. Once you establish 'comes before' / 'comes after' relationships between code, for example because you use a synchronized block, this arbitrary nature goes away, and you are guaranteed visibility (so if code A comes before code B, e.g. because they both synchronize on the same object and A 'won' the battle, anything A writes anywhere will be visible to B once B gets to run, guaranteed, because there is a CA/CB relationship here).

Put that null check inside and all of a sudden the problem goes away.

[2] If all you're trying to accomplish is that there is exactly one instance of `SingletonClass`, you're barking up the wrong tree. This is not how to do that. It is in fact TRIVIALLY simple. All you do, is this one line:

```
public class SingletonClass {
    public static final SingletonClass instance = new SingletonClass();

    private SingletonClass() {
        // ensure nobody but you can call this.
    }
}
```

That's it. You may think this means the class is initialized as your app boots, but that's not true. Classes are only loaded if some code is run that uses the class. Assuming ALL uses of SingletonClass involve getting that singleton instance (usually true), this is as good as anything. If for some bizarre reason code may interact with SC without grabbing the singleton, you can still use this mechanism, just, using an inner class:

```
public class SingletonClass {
    private SingletonClass() {}

    public static SingletonClass getInstance() {
        return Inner.instance;
    }

    private static class Instance {
        private static final SingletonClass instance = new SingletonClass();
    }
}
```

This guaranteed does not call that constructor until someone calls getInstance(), only calls it once, CANNOT ever call it twice, and does it in the most efficient way possible.

EDIT: Formatting.

Comment: Shared variables without thread safe mechanisms are worse than Schrödinger’s cat. After all, Schrödinger’s cat won’t become alive again after you’ve perceived the cat to be death… In other words, “*each thread has a copy of it, or doesn't*” is an oversimplification. Each individual read operation may end up at a different timeliness. A thread may read an up-to-date value, followed by using an outdated value in a subsequent read. That’s why approach 4 of the question may happen to work, but still is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

So problem was both threads can reach method at once and so both will get object as null at once before first one entering synchrosied block.

Using @rzwitserloot and @T.J. Crowder comments, I reached to conclusion that, it's not necessary to use synchronised for creating SIngleton object.
Below code can do that and it's been testing with thread tests n junits as well

```
package singleton;

public class SingletonClassSecond {

    private static SingletonClassSecond singleton = new SingletonClassSecond();

    private SingletonClassSecond() {
    }

    public static SingletonClassSecond getInstance(){
        return singleton;
    }
}

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

package singleton;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class SingletonClassTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldCreateSingleton(){
        SingletonClass singletonOne = SingletonClass.getInstance();
        SingletonClass singletonTwo = SingletonClass.getInstance();
        singletonOne.print("1");
        singletonTwo.print("2");
        Assertions.assertEquals(singletonOne.hashCode(),singletonTwo.hashCode());
    }

}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

package singleton;

class ThreadUsageTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new ThreadUsageSecond();
        Runnable runnableTwo = new ThreadUsageSecond();
        Runnable runnableThree = new ThreadUsageSecond();
        Runnable runnableFour = new ThreadUsageSecond();
        new Thread(runnable).start();
        new Thread(runnableTwo).start();
        new Thread(runnableThree).start();
        new Thread(runnableFour).start();
    }
}
```

---

Hashcode is same for all 4 threads.